# read from serial buffer

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial, c, rs232

I am trying to interface a dsPIC33EP chip with a RS232 device at baudrate=460800.
My code works OK but I think there must be a better way to do this. Here is the code:

```
void getData(unsigned char *Data) {
   int i=3;//EDIT: unsigned was removed
   UART1_Write(0x00);
   UART1_Write(0x86); //send two bytes of command to request data(4 bytes) back

   while (1) {

       if (U1STA.URXDA) {   // check if there is a byte available
         Data[i--]=U1RXREG; // shift a byte from UART1 internal receive buffer             
       }

       if (i == -1) break;
   }
}
```

It polls new byte available bit constantly until it reads all four bytes. The baud rate is quiet fast so I think there is no problem making this function a blocking call.

Here is another version of it:

```
void getData(unsigned char *Data){
   UART1_Write(0x00);UART1_Write(0x86);//send two bytes of command to request data(4 bytes) back
   *(Data+3)=U1RXREG;
   *(Data+2)=U1RXREG;
   *(Data+1)=U1RXREG;
   *(Data)=U1RXREG;
}
```

Because I am expecting exactly four bytes to come in, and the FIFO buffer on the dsPic chip is four, I don't need to worry about overrun. The chip runs at 120MHZ.

According to testing, both of them work but my application is time sensitive and I want to avoid any possible errors. Which way is better? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What if No data arrives?? You are stuck there in Loop!!

Comment: An unsigned int is not going to equal -1, no matter how much it is decremented.

Comment: I added a closing brace to the code and changed some whitespace.

Comment: @markrages Well, on my C compiler (gcc amd64) decrementing an unsingned int that is 0 and then checking against -1 **does** give *true*. It's not a good idea to rely on this, but that doesn't mean it can't happen.

Comment: Somehow my compiler(mikroC) does the same thing...But I just removed unsigned to be safe.

Comment: Implicit type conversion is allowing the comparison to succeed.  This is a dark corner of C, best avoided.  A decent compiler will warn about signed to unsigned comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are blatantly wrong.

The first method will loop inifinitely reading bytes from the UART and stuffing them into decreasing memory locations.  It will hang until the UART delivers enough bytes until eventually something sensitive in memory is overwritten or you get a address trap.

The second method doesn't even wait for the characters to be received.  it copies whatever is in U1RXREG at the time into the 4 bytes at DATA in backwards order.

Comment: So I guess using interrupts will be a better way? It's only four bytes and baudrate is fast enough can't I just make it one function?

Comment: @Timtia: You can make it one subroutine, but you have to fix the problems I mentioned.

Comment: I ended up using interrupts for each sensor instead. However, I am still playing around with setting priority bits because it sometimes gives buffer overrun error.